# How to prove $\frac{2\pi k}{2^n - 1}$ is dense in $[0, 2\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis

($n, k \in \mathbb{N}$) I interpret this question as needing to show that angles of the form $\frac{2\pi k}{2^n - 1}$ can always be represented as an angle in $[0, 2\pi)$. However, I can't visualize what angles of this form look like, so I'm not sure how to start this proof. Typically when I prove something is dense, such as proving rationals of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, I'll use some facts about $\mathbb{R}$ to begin with, such as ordering and the Archimedean property and arrive at a result like $a < \frac{m}{2^n} < b$ where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real numbers. But with angles, I can't use any of that, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Divide both the length of the interval and the numbers you are studying by $2\pi$: you will get $\frac{k}{2^n-1}$ being dense in $[0,1)$.

Comment: I think you may find the results on [dyadic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) relevant (that's essentially what you ask, with a small "twist").

Comment: There is no reason to think in terms of *angles*, the question asks about *numbers*.  One can make $\frac{2\pi}{2^n-1}$ arbitrarily small positive, so the numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b\in [0,2\pi)$ s.t $a<b$:

Let $n\in \mathbb N^*$ s.t $2^n-1>\displaystyle\frac{2\pi}{b-a}$, i.e $\displaystyle\frac{2pi}{2^n-1}<b-a $

Then $k=\max\{p\in\mathbb N|0\leq \displaystyle\frac{2p\pi}{2^n-1}<b \}$ (the set is non empty and bounded from above)

Then 
$$\frac{2k\pi}{2^n-1}<b \text{ and } \frac{2k\pi}{2^n-1}+\frac{2\pi}{2^n-1}\geq b$$

$$a<b-\frac{2\pi}{2^n-1} \leq\frac{2k\pi}{2^n-1}<b$$

So: $a<\displaystyle\frac{2k\pi}{2^n-1}<b$

Therefore that set is dense in $[0,2\pi)$

**Note:**

This proof may be adjusted to prove that if $u_n$ can become arbitrarily small, then numbers of the form $k\cdot u_n$ are dense in $\mathbb R$.

Here $u_n = \displaystyle\frac{2pi}{2^n-1}$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$, which means it becomes arbitrarily small for sufficiently large $n$.